# Determine height of div based on font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size, typography

I have the following code where font-size, line-height, and height are all defined to the same value. I would expect all of the font to be contained within the container.

```
#container{
    font-size:25pt;
    line-height:25pt;
    height:25pt;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

As you can see in the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/bmcalees/pen/VwvdKLM), the bottom of the 'p' is being chopped off by the div.

Requirements:

- overflow must be hidden
- text will always be on one line (no need to calculate for 2+ lines of text)

My question really comes down to **how I can determine the exact height of a div in inches given I know the point value of a font.**

Based on the second answer in this post [this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4035/what-does-the-size-of-the-font-translate-to-exactly) I would expect everything to fit within the div. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having problems with fitting content into your div or do you just want to calculate the size of the printing surface you need?

The height needed for the content to fit into this div would vary based on the amount of text. 
If you know how many lines there are in this text(based on the font-size), you can simply multiply that with the line-height. That would give you the size of the div in pt's.
After that you can use an online calculator such as [this one](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/conversions/length/points-to-inches.php) to calculate the full size.

The problem that I see with your CSS is that your line-height and font-size are exactly the same. This might(and probably will) cause problems with overlapping text, or in the best case scenario text that is hard to read.
This is what it would look like: [image]

I would probably go with the [standard/golden ratio](https://medium.com/@zkareemz/golden-ratio-62b3b6d4282a) of line height = font size*1.5

This is what that would look like:

[image]

Hope that answers your question.

Update:
So, you say your text is getting cut off. It's getting cut off because of your overflow: hidden property and the fact that your line-height and font-size are the same.
Check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bap29sn0/) out.

```
#container{
  font-size:25pt;
  line-height:1;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

what you can do to fix this is to omit the div height property and just increase the line height property(as explained above). If you really want to set the div height you can do so by putting it to 37.5pt(or 0.52083333333334in) as seen in this 
[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dx9Lafqk/)

```
#container {
  font-size: 25pt;
  line-height: 1.5;
  height: 0.52083333333334in;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Now there's no text being cut off and your div's height in pt is 37.5(font-size*1.5) or, as I said 0.52083333333334in.

If this answers your question tag this as an answer, otherwise comment and I will try to update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just updated my question to address what you've pointed out here. Fortunately, I don't need to worry about multiple lines of text. I simply need to figure out what the height should be for a div that contains a single line of text.

Comment: For 1 line of text with line-height of 25pt with no padding that would be 0.34722222222223in, according to the calculator I linked above.

Comment: Yeah I played with that calculator before to no avail. If you punch in that number as the height of the div in the CodePen, it still cuts off the text.

Comment: Sorry for the late response.
As I said in my post though, you should really avoid setting your font-size equal to your line-height. If those 2 values ARE the same then what you get is the text wont fit into your div(if you set it the same as font size). I'll update my answer with more info